# Multiple CSV to MySQL with Different Columns

Tags: php, mysql, csv, load-data-infile

I use the "load data infile" statement to load multiple .csv files in one table with a foreach loop. This works, only I have one problem. The columns in de .csv's are not the same. For example I have this:

CSV1:

> id,name,ean,description

CSV2:

> id,name,image,ean,description

And my MySQL table is:

> id,name,ean,description

So because I want to import multiple csv's through a loop, I have a problem with CSV2, because of the image column. If possible, I want to match the name of the csv column with the name of the table column. So in this example, [image] is not imported. I can use a @ignore variable, but because every .csv is different, this doesn't work. I have this:

```
$sql = "
   LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$value[path]'
       INTO TABLE db1.shoptest
       FIELDS TERMINATED BY '$value[seperator]'
       OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
       LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
     (id, name, ean, description)
    ;";
```

Is it possible to match the csv column names with the table column names and skip all other columns in the .csv?

Thanks so much for helping me out!

Kind regards,
Mark

Comment: To be clear.  Those are not the only two CSV file formats?

Answer (score 0):

I think I understood the question.  You wan't to get the column headers from the first row of the CSV, then build a string to use as the `col_name_or_user_var` argument of LOAD DATA and use @ignore variable assignments as needed.

`id, name, state, ean, favorite_color, description`

becomes...

`(id, name, @bunk, ean, @bunk, description)`

```
$whiteList = ['id', 'name', 'ean', 'description'];
$columnHeader = 'id, name, state, ean, favorite_color, description';
$columnHeader = explode(',', $s);
foreach ($columnHeader as $k => $v) {
    if (! in_array(trim($v), $whiteList)) $columnHeader[$k] = '@bunk';

}

echo implode(',', $columnHeaders);
```

Comment: Hi Ficuscr, Thanks so much for this answer! This works!! I'll test it better tomorrow. You're the best!!